# AJAX on Button Click runs incrementally

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've implemented a simple AJAX call that is bound to a button. On click, the call takes input from an  and forwards the value to a FLASK server using getJSON. Using the supplied value (a URL), a request is sent to a website and the html of a website is sent back.

The issue is the AJAX call seems to run multiple times, incrementally depending on how many times it has been clicked.

example;

(click)
1
(click)
2
1
(click)
3
2
1

Because I am sending requests from a FLASK server to another website, it effectively looks like I'm trying to DDOS the server. Any idea how to fix this?

My AJAX code;

```
var requestNumber = 1; //done for testing purposes

    //RUNS PROXY SCRIPT
    $("#btnProxy").bind("click", function() . //#btnProxy is the button
        {
     $.getJSON("/background_process", //background_process is my FLASK route
                   {txtAddress: $('input[name="Address"]').val(), //Address is the input box
                   },
                   console.log(++requestNumber), //increment on function call
                   function(data)
                   {$("#web_iframe").attr('srcdoc', data.result); //the FLASK route retrieves the html of a webpage and returns it in an iframe srcdoc.
                   });
        return false;
    });
```

My FLASK code (Though it probably isn't the cause)

```
@app.route('/background_process')
def background_process():
    address = None
    try:
        address = request.args.get("txtAddress")
        resp = requests.get(address)
        return jsonify(result=resp.text)

    except Exception, e:
        return(str(e))
```

Image of my tested output (I've suppressed the FLASK script)

https://snag.gy/bikCZj.jpg

Comment: try to remove any old events  $("#btnProxy").unbind("click"); $("#btnProxy").bind("click", function(){ ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest things to do would be to disable the button after the first click and only enable it after the AJAX call is complete:

```
var btnProxy = $("#btnProxy");
//RUNS PROXY SCRIPT
btnProxy.bind("click", function ()  //#btnProxy is the button
{
    btnProxy.attr('disabled', 'disabled');//disable the button before the request
    $.getJSON("/background_process", //background_process is my FLASK route
        {
            txtAddress: $('input[name="Address"]').val(), //Address is the input box
        },
        function (data) {
            $("#web_iframe").attr('srcdoc', data.result); //the FLASK route retrieves the html of a webpage and returns it in an iframe srcdoc.
           btnProxy.attr('disabled', null);//enable button on success
        });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `preventDefault()` and see if it fits your needs.

```
  $("#btnProxy").bind("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

   $.getJSON("/background_process", 
                 {txtAddress: $('input[name="Address"]').val(),
                 },
                 console.log(++requestNumber),
                 function(data)
                 {$("#web_iframe").attr('srcdoc', data.result);
                 });
      return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are binding the click event multiple times.

```
$("#btnProxy").bind("click", function() { ... } );
```

Possible solutions alternatives:

a) Bind the click event only on document load:

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnProxy").bind("click", function() { ... } );
});
```

b) Use setTimeout and clearTimeout to filter multiple calls:

```
var to=null;
$("#btnProxy").bind("click", function() {
    if(to) clearTimeout(to);
    to=setTimeout(function() { ... },500);
});
```

c) Clear other bindings before set your calls:

```
$("#btnProxy").off("click");
$("#btnProxy").bind("click", function() { ... } );
```